# Why The Anchor Is not Working In this Script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, redirect

I am a Template developer,

i created one script for footer credit link, so that the user cannot remove the footer link,

However, i am bit confuse why the anchor is not working ?

here is the script.

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var e = document.getElementById("credit");            
    e.setAttribute("href", "http://www.example.com/");
    e.setAttribute("ref", "dofollow");
    e.setAttribute("title", "Free Templates");
    e.innerHTML = "Example"

}
</script>
```

As you see the above script, i included that in my template and also i add the credit div in footer area like this:

```
<div id="credit"></div>
```

Now when i open my template, It seems as plain texts.

**Problem:** Why the Example seems as plain texts it is not anchor. how to make it clickable so that it should go to example.com if click.

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/copyblogger/dkt2jdxt/5/

**Note:** please share full coding with fiddle example.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<a id="credit"></a>
```

You've been setting attributes that a div tag does not have, but an a tag does.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply, it worked for me, thanks bundles.

Answer (score 1):

The `href` attribute is only supported on the following elements: `<a>`, `<area>`, `<base>`, `<link>`.

You could wrap the `<div>` in an `<a>` element and then the entire `div` would be clickable.